# UI5 - Load proper i18n_xy.properties at onInit and later on manually

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

We have the requirement, that we shall host an SAPUI5 application inside a java-application's host, which our vendor offered to us by implementing and exposing jxbrowser.

This vendor's java application offers an api, which can be accessed from within our SAPUI5 application.

This java api offers also an environment (or config-settings), where, amongst a rich set of settings, also a user language can be obtained.

And this language is neither a sap-logon language param nor is it guaranteed to be always the language which is set up in the "jx-browser" ( if possible at all, like in all real browsers ), and it uses the standard i18n _xy_AB acronym's naming style.

And I want to load the proper i18n_xy.properties at onInit of my first view and set them in the code.

We do have currently 4 of them ( _de,_it,_fr ), and the fallback is also present.

I am a little idiot, because I found some quick n dirty code, but this was about one month ago and I simply forgot the link and all of that. So now I need to ask( and maybe even for a best practice  solution to this...)

So, additionally, another (my personal) requirement is, that, once I retrieve the right i18n file, I want to set it, in a way, that, whenever later on, I would use

```
info = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("obfuscated");
```

I always obtain the right text in the right language.

What I think of, is: Load the proper file ( according to the environment settings from the api ) in onInit, set this i18n as the proper one for the rest of the application's runtime and use a easy name for it, which will then be referred to as, maybe this:

```
info = this.getView().getModel("i18n_loaded").getResourceBundle().getText("obfuscated");
```

Is this possible, is this the right way, and , if not, which one is, according to some kind of guidelines, the best practice for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter in the url:

```
sap-ui-language=en
```

Or set the default language in your JavaScript code:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("en-US");
```

Comment: Ok, thx, This is a nice approach, what about my second  ( personal ) question.... ?

Answer (score 0):

I was not completely aware, that the determination of the used locale also works the other way around.

Meaning, if the ressource bundle contains e.g. 4 i18's,called i18_en, i18_it, i18_de, i18_fr,  and the either the app is set up  by

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("en-US");
```

or the url-param, this not only means, that:

- All ui-elements will be translated propery, once the locale's acronym is properly spotted
- **ALSO this is automatically replaced by the proper spotted ressource file and the translated text is retrieved properly....**

  info = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("obfuscated");

I was aware of how this fallback determination of a locale works, but I was not aware that it works also the other way around.

I close my question and i do not care about any rewards.